# Array not duplicating a ParticleSystem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I have a ParticleSystem so that I can make grass on a plane that I have created.

I need the grassy area to be bigger so I tried to use the Array modifier to make it larger.

The ParticleSystem is not copying over to the arrayed part. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think that you may have to apply the particle modifier **after** the array modifier, as I don't think that the particle system gets duplicated like that. Remember to turn on Use Modifiers in the particle properties panel.

Comment: Oh, you have to turn on use modifiers? Let me see if this works :)

Comment: Actually, this didn't work...The particles are not duplicated how I had hoped, it just duplicates the mesh and applies the particles to that.

Comment: You misunderstood, the particles are not duplicated just spread over more mesh.

Comment: Agreed, but what I want to do is duplicate the mesh with particles.

Comment: I think that the particles use object space so they cannot be instanced like real geometry, however there is a particle instance modifier, perhaps that would help. But I don't recall exactly how it works.